# Not getting results from database

Tags: c#, sql

In my C# code, I'm trying to open a connection to a SQL Server database and get a count. I've copied the code (barring the query itself) from another application I wrote that works fine. I've run the query -- both the version I constructed, and the query the code constructs (I use variables) -- and they both work fine, returning an identical count. I'm just not getting anything back.

I've put in breakpoints and checked my connection and query, and it is what I expect. When I Googled this, I just got results for people having entirely different problems, so I'm stumped. I don't know why I'm not getting anything back. Where is the error?

```
SqlConnection RRconnection = new SqlConnection();
RRconnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User id=;Password=";

RRconnection.Open();
string ridQuery = "SELECT COUNT (t.RxTimeStamp) FROM...";

SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(ridQuery, RRconnection);

SqlDataReader data = query.ExecuteReader();

if (data.Read())
    transcount = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetValue(0));
```

In case the above paragraph wasn't clear, I'm expecting the query to return a count of 1592064 (for the specific instance I'm testing), and instead there's no data in `data`.

Probably not related, but my query includes three inner joins. It's the first time I've done that many, so maybe that could be the problem? Except if that was causing the problem, it wouldn't work when I run the query?

Comment: Try  var qty = (int)query.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a try/catch by any chance?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` will always return some data, it can be `0` or greater than that.

Comment: If you're not confident in the joins, maybe that's where the problem is. It would help to show the whole query (with anonymized table/columns, if you want). Is that count (1592064) what you got in SSMS? Also, you said "I use variables" but without seeing how you do that, I get this itchy "string concatenation" vibe.

Comment: More importantly... *"they both work fine, returning an identical count. I'm just not getting anything back."* ...how exactly does that work? Is the count not something you get back?

Comment: @mate That worked, thanks! Why did that work and what I had didn't?

Comment: @Amy No. I didn't really see the point. Should I have?

Comment: @Fabio It's not though, that's the problem. Not even 0.

Comment: @madreflection I'm only not confident bc it's 3 joins. It works perfectly when I execute it. I was only including that information on the off chance it was a contributing factor. The bit you quoted was referring to when I execute the queries. When I run my code and the queries execute from there, I get nothing back, not even 0.

Comment: @tiffanie No. What frequently happens is someone wraps their code in a `try { ...code... } catch {}`, where the catch is empty. They then report they have no errors, but leave out the fact that they are suppressing errors because they don't realize that's what they're doing or they view it as unimportant.  I wanted to rule out that possibility.

Comment: A `select count()` query will always return one row, one column..

Comment: If you're starting over, now would be a great time to learn Dapper ( http://dapper-tutorial.net ) and stop using this prehistoric way of accessing db; there's nearly no good reason to do database access this way, and definitely for what you're using it for it's just way more pain than it needs to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar)

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(ridQuery, RRconnection);
Int32 transcount = (Int32) query.ExecuteScalar();
```

**Update**

I am not sure why your query did not work, maybe try giving the count column an **alias**:

```
string ridQuery = "SELECT COUNT (t.RxTimeStamp) AS RxCount FROM ...";
```

Comment: @tiffanie I'm not sure either, but you can try turning on tracing for `System.Data`, then re-run the code and look at the trace output.  It might have a clue.

Comment: Your query working right but executescalar gives the result row count. You should use this for getting the count. The other acustomed work is to iterating result data in this case you can read it by a while do. Maybe you cant see any result on your result variable because it's zero value check it by debugging

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use `ExecuteScalar` if the query returns a single value.

> **ExecuteScalar;** return object value so must be `Convert` to the correct type

```
int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

**So, to the you question**

It's a `ExecuteReader` don't use to get a `Select Count` result, but there's no problem this code. You can see the total count value for this code.

***Note*** : The SqlDataReader Object is a stream-based and forward-only retrieval of query results from the Data Source.
The `Read` method processes only one row in memory then overwrites old record when itterate next row.

> **ExecureReader;** In your case , reader first row and first column filled query result, other rows and column set to null.

```
if(reader.Read())
{
   int totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));  //convert returned value        
}
```

Note : use column name and use reader spesific type convert method is my best choice.

```
reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("TotalCount"))
```

**Advice,**

- Don't use `ExecuteReader` read for single value
- Use `ExecuteScalar` then cast result to correct type
- Use `IDisposible` objects (Connection , Command , Reader) inside to `using` code blog. using block close and dispose current object.
- You should not read `using` code blog on column index value

Comment: `//Returned object must be cast`  That line of code does not contain a *cast*.  It contains a *conversion*.  Those are distinct operations.  And as the other comment said, it's "scal**a**r".  You need to edit your answer and clean up the grammar.

Comment: @Amy , thank you for your correction.  
I corrected the mistakes in my answer.